# Why is apt filling up disk space that `apt-get clean` frees?

Tags: apt

Every now and then I've to run `apt-get clean` on some small systems I manage I want to free up some disk space and `apt` is slowly filling up my disk. A `apt-get clean` often releases 700 mb of disk space. Why is `apt` filling up my disk. I rarely use `apt`, so it are no my actions that make `apt` filling disk space. Some systems are not even connected to the Internet. How do I stop `apt` from filling up my disk?

Comment: What makes you think apt is filling your disk with logging? It's filling your disk with _packages_, and they must have come from somewhere. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Maintenance_commands

Comment: I was a guess, edited question. Ty.

Answer (score 2):

`apt` routines are called whenever a system update is made (e.g. with Ubuntu's Update Manager).

Any packages downloaded this way are kept for until you explicitly purge the, as you do when calling `apt-get clean`.

If disk space is at a premium, and your update manager runs automatically every day at e.g 8:00, you can set up a cron job to run at 8:30 to do the clean up. The only penalty is that if you delete a package and then want to reinstall, it has to be downloaded once more.

Comment: But how can it download packages on systems with no internet connection?

Comment: @OrangeTux Are the amounts equal between connected and not connected systems (assuming same amounts of time between cleanup and similar configurations)?